# Passing variable from component into a slot

Tags: laravel, components, laravel-blade

Is it possible to pass a variable from component into a slot.
Here is an example:

```
{{-- index.blade.php --}}
@component('slider', ['entities' => [0, 1, 2]])
    @slot('title')
        Slider title
    @endslot
    @slot('slide')
        Slider content no {{ $entity }}
    @endslot
@endcomponent


{{-- slider.blade.php --}}
<h1>{{ $title }}</h1>
<ul>
@foreach($entities as $entity)
    <li>{{ $slide }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Current result :

> Exception : $entity is not defined

Expected result:

```
<h1>Slider title</h1>
<ul>
    <li>Slider content no 0</li>
    <li>Slider content no 1</li>
    <li>Slider content no 2</li>
</ul>
```

- How can I pass the $entity variable into the slide slot?
- Is it even possible to do so?
- If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: What's the result you actually have?

Comment: Returns an exception saying that $entity is not defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to pass data from a component to a slot context. It is also the case with `@section`/`@yield`.

What I've discovered is the `@each` function. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#rendering-views-for-collections

You'd need to have another view partial for the list item content (called `item` here).

```
{{-- index.blade.php --}}
@component('slider', ['entities' => [0, 1, 2], 'item_view' => 'item'])
    @slot('title')
        Slider title
    @endslot
@endcomponent


{{-- item.blade.php --}}
<li>
  Slider content no $entity
</li>


{{-- slider.blade.php --}}
<h1>{{ $title }}</h1>
<ul>
  @each($item_view, $entities, 'entity')
</ul>
```

Example: making a new slider with different content:

```
{{-- gallery.blade.php --}}
@component('slider', ['entities' => ['a.png', 'b.png', 'c.png'], 'item_view' => 'gallery_item'])
    @slot('title')
        Gallery
    @endslot
@endcomponent


{{-- gallery_item.blade.php --}}
<li>
  <img src={{ $entity }} />
</li>
```

Comment: I like your solution, its similar to my workaround, but looks more compact than
`@foreach($entities as $entity) @include('components.slider.slide.' . $type, ['entity' => $entity]) @endforeach`

Answer (score 2):

We can try with different way. Here, how I executed.

```html
{{-- index.blade.php --}}
@component('slider', ['entities' => [0, 1, 2]])
      @slot('title')
          Slider title
      @endslot
      @slot('slide')
          Slider content no 
      @endslot
  @endcomponent

                    
{{-- slider.blade.php --}}                    
<h1>{{ $title }}</h1>
<ul>
@foreach($entities as $entity)
    <li>{{ $slide }} {{ $entity }}</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, but that beats the purpose of using a slot in the first place.
My goal was to use the slider view to handle the process of sliding and then put specific content/div inside. 
This way I could reuse the slider logic to build sliders containing different things, one containing a list of users, other with top comments, and other with images.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** I created a package adding scoped slots feature to Blade. Your problem is a perfect use-case for the scoped slots and it can be easily resolved using them. [Check it out](https://github.com/konradkalemba/blade-components-scoped-slots).

---

I struggled with the same problem and finally I found a way to "pass" variables from component to slot. The trick is to use [`@verbatim`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#displaying-data) directive which makes blade code not compile. Therefore we're able to pass blade code to a slot and then compile it in our component. However there is only one condition -- the name of variable used in `foreach` loop has to be the same as the one used in the slot. (As shown in the example below -- the `slide` slot uses `$entity` variable and so does the `foreach` loop in the component)

**index.blade.php**

```
@component('slider', ['entities' => [0, 1, 2]])
  @slot('title')
    Slider title
  @endslot

  @slot('slide')
    @verbatim
      Slide {{ $entity }}

      @if ($entity === 0) {{-- Directives also work! --}}
        <strong>Special slide</strong>
      @endif
    @endverbatim
  @endslot
@endcomponent
```

**slider.blade.php**

```
<h1>{{ $title }}</h1>
<ul>
  @foreach($entities as $entity)
    <li>{!! eval('?>'.Blade::compileString($slide)) !!}</li>
  @endforeach
</ul>
```

It is a little "hacky" solution to the problem but most importantly it does the job as you can see on the screenshot below.

[image: The result of the code above]