# Laravel: Pass variable to Blade Sub Component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

There are many questions here that are similar to mine, such as:

- [Pass variable to a component Laravel 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73262511/pass-variable-to-a-component-laravel-9)
- [Cannot access Blade Component variables inside the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66790126/cannot-access-blade-component-variables-inside-the-view)
- [Passing variable from component into a slot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50526057/passing-variable-from-component-into-a-slot)

but I have not found a resolution to my problem in any of them.  I've also scoured the doc at: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#components

I would have thought this would be a simple task.

I have the following structure, in Resources/views:

```
start.blade.php (uses)
   components/layout.blade.php (uses)
       components/head.blade.php
```

From my controller, I call:

```
$data =
[
    'total' => $total,
    'uses_form' => true
];

return view('start', $data);
```

Inside start.blade.php, I have:

```
<x-layout>
    <x-slot name="uses_form">
        {{ $uses_form }}
    </x-slot>

    <!-- additional html -->
</x-layout>
```

Inside layout.blade.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <x-head :uses_form:$uses_form />
  <!-- also tried: @include('includes.header', ['uses_form' => $uses_form])-->
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

    {{ $slot }}

    </div><!--container-fluid-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Finally, in head.blade.php:

```
  <head>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css' />
@if ($uses_form === true)
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/css/form.css' />
@endif
  </head>
```

This results in an:

```
Undefined variable $uses_form
```

at:

```
head.blade.php: line 3
```

How can I get the variable to be recognized in head.blade.php?

I'm open to other approaches, such as generated the conditional style include, at a higher level, but I rather keep this check in head.blade.php for maintainability.

Using Laravel version 9.48.0

**Edit** (Additional Notes)

If I `var_dump $uses_form` from the top of layout.blade.php, I get the following:

```
object(Illuminate\View\ComponentSlot)#301 (2) {
 ["attributes"]=> object(Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag)#299 (1) {
    ["attributes":protected]=> array(0) { }
    }
    ["contents":protected]=> string(1) "1"
}
```

So, it's already changed form.

Comment: Is `includes` a folder? I saw it in the `@includes('include.header ...`

Comment: @ÁlvaroPérezDíaz - Yes, includes is a folder.  But preferring to go the full component route

Comment: in ```<x-head :uses_form:$uses_form />```, will be ```:uses_form="$uses_form"```

Comment: @bluestar0505 - While putting the quotes around the variable may help, there is another issue to be solved beforehand, $uses_form is no longer a Boolean variable, but instead has been transformed into a ComponentSlot object.

Comment: As @bluestar0505 pointed out, your attribute value is in a nonsensical format. And when you use `{{ $uses_form }}` you are echoing the value which is why it changes to a 1. If you need to pass the raw value don't use a slot, use an attribute as you do elsewhere.

Comment: e.g. `<x-layout :uses_form='$uses_form'>`

Comment: Never mind, just noticed you self-answered. Not sure why that other answer got 2 upvotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working.  There were a few things needing adjusting, but, mainly, I needed to modify the component **classes** to accept the parameter data.

Another change that was needed, was to pass the data to the layout component, at the top of start.blade.php, like so:

```
<x-layout :hasForm="$hasForm">
```

Also, as indicated in another answer and in comments, I needed to place the variable in quotes.

Finally, I'm not sure if this was part of problem, but I changed the uses_form variable from snake_case to camelCase.

The changes, from the question are such:

Controller:

```
$data =
[
    'total' => $total,
    'hasForm' => true
];

return view('start', $data);
```

start.blade.php

```
<x-layout :hasForm="$hasForm">
    <!-- additional html -->
</x-layout>
```

app/View/Components/Layout.php

```
class Layout extends Component
{
    public $hasForm;

    public function __construct($hasForm)
    {
        $this->hasForm = $hasForm;
    }
}
```

layout.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <x-head :hasForm:"$hasForm" />
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

    {{ $slot }}

    </div><!--container-fluid-->
  </body>
</html>
```

app/Views/Components/Head.php

```
class Head extends Component
{
    public $hasForm;

    public function __construct($hasForm)
    {
        $this->hasForm = $hasForm;
    }
}
```

head.blade.php

```
  <head>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css' />
@if ($hasForm === true)
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/css/form.css' />
@endif
  </head>
```

Hope this may help someone else, down the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to pass the variable **$uses_form** from the parent component **layout.blade.php** to the child component **head.blade.php** using following changes and I hope it will helpful to you.

**layout.blade.php look like:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <x-head :uses-form="$uses_form"/>
  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    {{ $slot }}
    </div><!--container-fluid-->
  </body>
</html>
```

**head.blade.php look like:**

```
<head>
  <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css' />
  @if ($usesForm === true)
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='/css/form.css' />
  @endif
</head>
```

Comment: The only difference I see here, is the variable in quotes at: <x-head :uses-form="$uses_form"/>  That didn't change the result.  Can you  itemize your changes to indicate how it will work now?